# Telegram bot Deployment on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, telegram-bot

I use ASP.NET Core

Actually I published my Bot to Created WebApp via Azure and took necessary things (URL, password etc).

Now I have no idea how to test it before registration.

Also will be glad to get more information about working principle of the deployed on Azure bot

Comment: Did you manually publish the files or via Visual Studio Publish wizard?

Comment: @Tango via Visual Studio